# Spanner - How to find table size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

cloud spanner in database detail has: Total storage.

[image]

Can i take this value by query?

Also how to find tables sizes (by query). At the end of which will be total storage size.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Spanner table sizes aren't currently exposed.

Comment: Total storage? Can i take this value by query?

Comment: Currently there is no way to query for this value.

Answer (score 2):

To get a **general idea** of the tables size porportions, we check the resulted `avro` files sizes when exporting the DB (we have a daily job for backup).
Of-course it is not accurate since it's a whole different storage model.

Comment: Thank you. We need calculate average size for one row and then calculate size by our customers' rows. But because there is not possibility to find Table size, we have to run calculate queries :( and additionally use resources.

Comment: this situation will be hard to apply when you have TBs of data in your DB

Answer (score 1):

Just released table size statistics system table that includes table and index sizes. Sample query from docs:

```
SELECT interval_end
      ,table_name
      ,used_bytes
FROM spanner_sys.table_sizes_stats_1hour
WHERE interval_end = 
      (
      SELECT MAX(interval_end)
      FROM spanner_sys.table_sizes_stats_1hour
      )
ORDER BY used_bytes DESC;
```

See full details at https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/introspection/table-sizes-statistics

Comment: you can modify the used bytes to get the value in GB 
`used_bytes/1024/1024/1024 as GB`